# Why does the word "atheism" exist?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion

Why does the word "atheism" exist? There is no such word for people who disbelieve in astrology or Santa Claus or dragons. So, why does the word exist? Is it because most societies today and in history have marginalized non-religious people? I apologize if this question is not appropriate for Philosophy stack exchange. If it is not, it should be migrated to an appropriate SE.

Comment: Yes, ["*atheos*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atheism) came up in antiquity as a derogatory label used by believers to marginalize the non-religious ("godless") people. It was only adopted as a self-label in the age of Enlightenment in 18th century. Appropriation of slurs by the slurred is a common pattern, history has its ironies.

Comment: You like so many other people define the term incorrectly. Atheism is NOT defined as someone who disbelieves in God.  Athiesm correctly expresses the REJECTION of there being a God existing. So a new born is NOT an atheist!!  Surely a new born does not believe in God as you and other people incorrectly define the term. There are several cases where a person doesn't believe in a God and there is no atheism.  A theist is a person who accepts God exist and does in fact exist whereas an atheist REJECTS the possibility God exists.  Pass on the correct definition.

Comment: @Logikai Both definitions are in use ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atheism) cites yours to its sources 1, 2, 7 and 8, and the definition you decry to sources 1-4). Out of curiosity, when you say "a new born does not believe in God as you and other people incorrectly define the term", do you mean to say, as it sounds like you do, that some other term e.g. _God_ has been incorrectly defined?

Comment: @J.G. it is certainly possible people can be ambiguous with terms especially GOD. But if we agree to a definition of God some people still have too much emotion & irrationality about the word Atheism. In logic we would symbolize the phrase xis a person who willingly believes a God exists in the universe as Gx: where the x is represents an arbitrary person. Thus the ATHIEST is the REJECTION of a belief in a God. How we word statements can play an important role in interpretation. Too many humans think ATHEIST litearlly means lack of belief. So that tells me they do not understand concepts.

Comment: @Logikai Ah, I see. The term people were defining incorrectly was *believe*. Incidentally, your notation can only be used to formalize the definition you're against, viz. not-Gx.

Comment: Atheism is a philosophical term and so is theism.

Comment: It's kind of strange to be so picky about definitions. Then how should we call a newborn, or the same newborn once adult if they simply never where introduced to the concept of deity? They clearly are not agnostic, for the notion that they can't know god requires them to know the concept exist. Atheism is just simply not such a well defined concept, and anyone who claims to stick to a given definition is in their right, but pretending that every one else is wrong in all caps is just being pedantic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Words become a part of standard language because they are useful to a lot of people. There is very little use for referring to the class of people who disbelieve in astrology or Santa Claus or dragons; there are a lot of uses for referring to the class of people who disbelieve in God.

You are probably working under some sort of implicit assumption that because language is a social phenomenon that the evolution of language has an element of deliberation. This is not the case. Think of it like an ant trail. No ant or committee of ants decides to make a long line of foragers to your trash can; the situation develops organically as the individual actions of a lot of different ants.

Language works the same way, as do economic and cultural changes. These large social movements generally evolve without conscious control of any individual or group. Of course, certain individuals or groups are more influential than others; the owner of the New York times has a lot more influence on the direction of language than, say, your local butcher, but even he can't control it entirely. No one can.

Governments may be able to somewhat control the direction of major social changes, but even they fail eventually. Witness the inability of the Academie francaise to prevent imports of loan words. More spectacularly, note the various attempts by socialist and communist governments to control the economy and culture. No matter how many people they tortured, imprisoned, and killed (in some cases it was millions), they almost all eventually failed. Others, like North Korea and China are still torturing, imprisoning, and killing people in an endless horror show to keep their regime in power. Social change is just very difficult to control.

So if you are looking for a reason in the sense of "why did someone decide to make 'atheism' a word", there isn't any such reason. It was just an evolution of language.

Comment: Yes. I am sure that Mathematics evolved similarly, yet it converged on a common, accepted base. It is too bad that something as important as communication still wanders like a lost soul. Why doesn't it converge? (Don't get me started on the difference between envy and jealousy)

Answer (score 1):

> ATHÉE n. xvie siècle. Emprunté, par l'intermédiaire du latin chrétien atheos, « qui ne croit pas en Dieu », du grec atheos, « qui ne croit pas aux dieux ».

According to this current Académie Française definition, the word "athée" apparently only started to be used (in French) in the 16th century, borrowed through the *Christian* Latin "atheos", meaning "who doesn't believe *in God*" to the Greek word "atheos", meaning "who doesn't believe *in gods*". People make up words, sometimes deliberately, as obviously in this case, because they need or just want to name something. It should be noticed that this definition doesn't do justice to the fact that it wears its semantics on its sleeve, as it were, because rather than "who doesn't *believe* in God", the meaning of "atheist" is on the face of it just "godless". And, "godless", which also means what it says, is also used in English as the slur "Lacking reverence or immoral". I expect this is the original intention in the creation of the word "atheos" in Greek, its use in Christian Latin, and its use in French or English. I wasn't there at the time but this is what seems to be the most plausible interpretation.

Comment: Language: designed to insult people. God help us!

Comment: @ScottRowe "*designed to insult people*" Not quite what I said. The implication of what I said is that the label "atheist" was from the start used to identify non-believers as not being part of the community of believers, which often could be understood as not being part of the city (nation, society etc.). The mere existence of non-believers seriously exercised the theologians of the time.

Comment: Well, at least they were getting some exercise. You did say, used in English as a slur. Slur is related to insult, right? It's like other words that mean "people who are not like us". People still use it that way, I guess. People should realize that they have a lot in common with everyone else. Then the problem goes away.

Comment: @ScottRowe "*You did say, used in English as a slur*" And this is true, but I didn't say that it was designed to insult people. Rather, it was motivated by the desire to achieve discrimination.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it accurate to say in general that non-religious people have been marginalised.  Distribution of goods in pre-coinage societies had a great deal to do with priests and temples.  Thus its interesting to note that ideologies which are atheistic, or very close to it, emerge soon after coin use at markets begins:  Democritus, Buddha, Confucius……

Arguably Democritus was intentionally somewhat marginalised by Plato, and very much more so after Constantine made Christianity the European State religion.  What seems little noticed is that Francis Bacon specifically called for a return to the ideas of Democritus in 1620, and this seems to trigger a British Whiggish movement that becomes ever more pro-science, anti-religion and pro-democratic, all the way down to Russell.

Most of the big critics of Wittgenstein seem to be dead, but I notice Grayling soldier's on, pointing to the religious tenancies in Witts ideas.  Thus I think you have a point when you make non-religious people as marginalised if you look specifically at Britain c. 410 to 1620, and again in recent times, (say, since death of Russell, 1970, is my impression)

Having in mind my first paragraph – is it not thought provoking that Keynes, an atheist who valued religion for pragmatic purposes, was very involved indeed in getting Wittgenstein back to England in 1929?